# How to tell when to use the descriptive de and the possessive de

Tags: grammaire, traduction, de

Here's the theory I've been trying to apply: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/de-vs-du-de-la-des-description/
What it's telling me is that figuring out when to use de or de/de la/des is more than anything else about determining whether you're dealing with a possession or a description. In practice however, it often seems random to me if a description is involved or instead a possession. For instance "wine list" translates to "carte des vins", yet "bicycle race" translates to "course de vélo". Where's the difference? What other pointers do I need to watch out for?

Answer (score 5):

- For instance "wine list" translates to "carte des vins", yet "bicycle race" translates to "course de vélo". Where's the difference?

  Both *de* are descriptive here (the wines do not own the list and the bicycles do not own the race). In the first phrase, there is a known set of wines available in a given restaurant. They are in that list so the definite article is used:

  > *La carte "**de** les" vins* → *La carte **des** vins*

  In the second one, we are talking about a generic kind of race where some undetermined bicycles compete.

  > *La course **de** vélo.* (which by the way is colloquial, we often say *la course cycliste*)

  Sometimes both can be used and the nuance can be slight. Compare:

  > *Une/la liste de courses.* A/the shopping list.

  > ***La** liste des courses.* The precise list of things to buy.

Comment: That make sense. Thanks.

Comment: I tend to just say course vélo, course de vélo sounds off to me

Comment: @Eauquidort Ah oui ? Autant *course automobile* me semble courant, autant *course vélo* me semble bizarre. Google NGram a d'ailleurs du mal a en trouver, il y a même bien plus de *course en vélo* pourtant critiqué.

Answer (score -5):

There is no such simple method as you suppose could exist.

You have to realize one thing, which I think a careful appreciation of this [TLFi page](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) will make clear to you, the preposition "de" is  saturted with a plentiful assignation of relations of all sorts that even a lifetime spent in living in the country is not sufficient to make clear unless you are an avid reader; it is  not something you can treat in a couple of short paragraphs as you might suppose from Lawless French. In this reference, it is nevertheless mentioned that ***sometimes*** the claim is true, but that is far from exact; given the bulk of possibilities it is rather rare. You might say it is true if construed in a very approximate fashion but that is not enough, does not tell you enough. To say that, for instance, in "le train de  Paris à Brest", "de" enters into the phrase in a relation of description is not entirely wrong, but it does not tell you what that train does or is: is it a train coming from Paris, is it "train" in general meaning "travelling by train" or is it something else ?

I will give examples for a few of the relations; their identification according to the dictionary is found in the second part (**II**); this second part is a condensed version,  of the TLFi entry for this preposition; it is but a skeleton in which a mass of variants and subtleties are missing and in the end one has to go back to the TLFi. However, so as to practice and to get an idea of what one is struggling with I included it in this answer because it is easier to get at the main divisions (the parts that are not needed are also included, for instance those concerning the preposition as introducing a verbal complement ). I can't give an example for all relations and it is left to you to do that as an exercice when you feel like it. Moreover, there are a lot of difficulties, as for instance "faire  des vêtements de  vieille étoffe démodée", where it is not clear whether "de vieille étoffe démodée" is "complément du verbe" or "complément prépositionnel de "vêtement".

As concerns "carte des vins" and "course de vélo" it seems that, broadly speaking, it can be said that the relation is one of description in both cases (a sort of card, a sort of race); more specifically the first could be "*purpose*" (made to provide the list of wines, "*carte pour les vins"*) and the second "*means*" (race made by the means of bicycles, *course avec des vélo*).

**I**

- le train **de** Paris vers Brest  (*point of departure: Paris*)
- le garçon **de** Paris est là    (*origin*)
- pastille **de** menthe, purée de pommes de terre       (*matter out of which is made sth*)
- différencier « oreille » **de** « oseille » (*shows difference to be made, Eng: from*)
- de la guerre **de** l'année 45 jusqu'à la fin    (*start of a situation in time*)
- une largeur **de** trente mètres  (*affectation of an attribute; you might say "description here: the width is described as being 30 meters.*)
- le livre **de** Pierre (*possession*)
- une maison **de** fous  (*description, a house where people behave like mad men*)
- une maison **de** fous (*description, sort of house, this sort being a hospital*)

**II**

de, prép. [Quotation  marks have not been introduced where in the text from which issues the copy they were coded as italics.]

I.− De prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.
A.− De exprime le point de départ.
1/ [Orig. spatio-temporelle.] Le point de départ se situe dans l'espace ou dans le temps (s'oppose à la prép. à, parfois à en, plus rarement à jusqu'à), par rapport à un point d'aboutissement dans l'espace ou dans le temps.
a) De... à.Synon. depuis... jusqu'à.
b) De... en.[Pour indiquer les limites d'une étendue, les étapes d'une progression]
2/ Le point de départ se situe dans l'espace.
a) De marque le lieu d'où l'on vient, le point de départ d'un mouvement.
b) De marque la séparation, la privation, l'origine, la provenance.,1945, p. 170.
c) De marque l'extraction. Sucres d'orge, pastilles de menthe.
d) De marque la distinction, la différenciation (d'une chose, d'(avec) une autre ou d'un être).
e) [De marque la direction séparative, la situation, le point de vue où l'on se place ]
f) [De dans un compl. déterminatif de lieu (espace neutralisé)]
3/ Le point de départ est un moment du temps.
a) De marque le point de départ d'un laps de temps (de signifie à partir de, à compter de, depuis, dès).
b) De marque une date, une époque.
c) De dépend d'un terme exprimant la durée. À quelque temps de là; il y a longtemps de cela  là, d'ici peu.
d) P. ext. De précise le moment où se déroule l'action (cf. infra).
e) De introduit un compl. déterminatif de temps pouvant exprimer toutes les nuances ci-dessus énumérées.
4/ Le point de départ est une personne.
a) De marque la provenance. Recevoir qqc. de qqn
b) De marque la descendance, la filiation; l'origine.
c) De marque la séparation, la distinction, la distance, la différence.
d) Faire qqc. de qqn. Cf. infra moyen, et aussi point de départ d'une transformation et obj.
5/ Le point de départ est une situation antérieurement donnée.
a) Le point de départ est une situation concrète.
b) Le point de départ est une situation abstraite. Il résulte de tout cela que...; de ces prémisses on peut conclure que...
6/ Le point de départ est un tout dont on tire une partie.
a) Verbe + de.Donner de son temps (de « un peu, une partie de »).
b) Subst. + de.De a une valeur partitive, proche de celle de l'article partitif. Cf. de2et des II (en parlant d'une partie, d'un ensemble, d'un élément d'un tout).
c) Être de + subst.Faire partie de (le pron. pers. correspondant est en).
7. Le point de départ est une entité à partir de laquelle on évalue, par comparaison, une autre entité.
a) De marque le superl. de construction hébraïque exprimant l'excellence, le degré parfait, par le redoublement du subst. ou de l'adj.; d'où les loc. bibliques ou formées sur ce modèle (presque toujours au plur.).
b) Devant le second terme d'une comparaison exprimée par
B.− De marque la condition préalable d'un procès ou du résultat d'un procès matériel ou moral.
1/ [La condition préalable est une matière] Faire qqc. de rien.
a) Verbe + de.
b) Subst. + de + subst. : le compl. déterminatif.Concurrence de/en : de est plus littér. et s'emploie surtout dans des loc. au fig.
c) Adj. + de.Noir de jais, noir d'encre, etc.
d) Verbe d'état + de/en.
2/ [Dans un compl. déterminatif (genre, espèce)]
a) [En parlant d'animés ou d'inanimés concr. (races d'animaux, variétés de plantes, essences d'arbres, espèces, etc.)]
b) [En parlant d'inanimés abstr.]
3/ [Le compl. désigne un contenu]
4/ [Le compl. désigne la totalité d'un ensemble, des parties composant un ensemble]
5/ [La condition préalable est la matière d'un propos]
a) Verbes ou loc. verbales d'énonciation ou de jugement + de
b) Gallicismes
c) Subst. + de.De signifie « qui traite de ».
6/ [La condition préalable est un moyen à partir duquel une chose a ou peut avoir lieu] De marque le moyen, l'instrument ou l'intermédiaire. Il signifie « à l'aide de » et entre en concurrence avec par et avec.
a) [Le compl. désigne une pers.] De signifie « par l'intermédiaire de; par le truchement de; avec l'aide de; par l'entremise de; avec le concours de; grâce à, etc. »
b) [Le compl. désigne une partie du corps] .
c) [Le compl. désigne une chose]
d) Le compl. n'est plus senti comme moyen, mais comme obj.
7/ [La condition préalable est un agent ou un auteur]
a) [De introduit le compl. d'agent d'un verbe à la voix passive (cf. aussi les prép. à et par).]
b) P. ext. [De introduit le compl. d'un part. passé en fonction adj. (le compl. d'agent n'est plus senti comme tel, il s'agit de part. d'un verbe d'état, c'est le simple compl. de l'adj.).]
c) [De introduit un compl. déterminatif précisant l'auteur d'une œuvre littér. ou artistique.]
8/ [La condition préalable est une cause, un motif; lorsque le compl. est un subst., celui-ci est souvent indéterminé]
a) [Le compl. est un subst.]
b) [Le compl. est un verbe] De signifie « par le fait que; du fait que ».
c) De introduisant un inf. suj.;de signifie « le fait de », en parlant d'un fait particulier, ce tour littér. est assez répandu (cf. infra II B 1).
C.− De marque une circonstance qui précise (et parfois conditionne) une modalité d'existence ou d'action.
1/ La modalité est un moment du temps; de précise le moment où se déroule l'action.
2/ La modalité est une mesure, une évaluation (nombre, quantité, poids, dimension, âge, mensuration, distance, prix, etc.), la question correspondante est de combien?
a) Adj. + de + nombre.
b) Subst. + de + nombre.
c) Nombre + de + subst.
3/ La modalité est une destination habituelle ou occasionnelle d'une pers., d'un animal ou d'une chose (but, fin, usage); de signifie pour et introduit un compl. déterminatif (cf. aussi caractérisation, genre, espèce, qualité, etc.).
a) Pour qqn (destination attributive, de « à »; « pour »).
b) Pour qqc.
a) Verbe + de.[Souvent avec des verbes indiquant une expr. du visage, ou avec des verbes de déclaration]
b) Part. passé-adj. + de (+ le compl. de l'adj.)
d) Compl. de manière dit « figure étymologique » ou « obj. interne » qui qualifie l'action du verbe par un subst. déverbal (ou ayant la même racine sémantique que le verbe).
e) Loc. adv. de manière. D'habitude, de coutume, d'usage, d'avis, etc. (cf. infra III de formateur de locutions).
4/ La modalité est une manière d'être ou de se comporter. [Le compl. de + subst. ou pron. est souvent indéterminé, notamment dans des loc. verbales ou adv. au fig.; il correspond à un adv. ou au gérondif, p. ex. accepter de bon cœur « volontiers, en étant d'accord, avec joie »]
a) Verbe + de.[Souvent avec des verbes indiquant une expr. du visage, ou avec des verbes de déclaration]
b) Part. passé-adj. + de (+ le compl. de l'adj.)
c) Loc. verbales où le compl. de moyen est devenu un compl. de manière.
d) Compl. de manière dit « figure étymologique » ou « obj. interne » qui qualifie l'action du verbe par un subst. déverbal (ou ayant la même racine sémantique que le verbe).
5/ La modalité est une appartenance.
a) Possession, dépendance.
b) Qualité, détermination, qualification, caractérisation.
II.− De marque une relation syntaxique; il est introducteur de subst., de pron. ou d'inf. en fonction de compl., de suj., d'attribut, d'appos., ou en fonction expressive.
A.− [De introducteur de compl.]
1/ [Compl. de verbes ou de loc. verbales.]
a) Verbes trans. indir.
b) Verbes trans. à double constr. [De introduit l'obj. second de certains verbes trans.]
2/ [Compléments de noms]
a) [Le nom est un nom déverbal (transposition de phrase verbale).]
b) [Le nom n'est pas un déverbal.] Le livre de Pierre, cf. I C 5, l'appartenance, et tous les compl. déterminatifs.
3/ [Compl. d'adj.]
a) Adj. (parfois issu d'un verbe) + de (indiquant une action ou un sentiment)
b) Adj. (substantivé) + de.
c) Part. passé-adj. + de (du verbe à la forme passive).
d) Adj. + de (compl. de l'adj.)
e) [Les compl. de l'adj. au comparatif et au superl.] (cf. infra de partitif et la comparaison).
B.− [De introducteur de suj., d'attributs, d'appos.; de signifie « le fait de », en parlant d'un fait particulier.]
1/ De + inf. suj.[(tour littér. assez répandu; de a une valeur expressive plutôt que syntaxique).]
a) [En tête de phrase.]
b) [Annoncé par un pron. neutre.]
2/ De + attribut
a) De + attribut du suj.
− Dans des gallicismes
b) de + attribut du compl. d'obj. dir. apr. des verbes comme traiter, qualifier, taxer, accuser; gratifier (qqn, qqc.) de.
a) [Dénomination de choses, avec un nom propre]
b) [Dénomination de pers.]
C.− [De introducteur du noyau verbal dans un énoncé expressif à l'inf.]
1/ [L'inf. de narration]
2/ De + inf. dans l'expression du passé immédiat :venir de, (vx) ne faire que de.
3/ De + inf. dans l'expression d'une comparaison.
III.− De élément formateur de loc. adv., prépositives, conj., etc.
A.− Loc. adv. ayant souvent la valeur d'un compl. circonstanciel (temps, lieu, manière, etc.)
1/ De + subst.
a) De + subst. indéterminé.D'abord, d'ailleurs, d'avance, d'emblée, de grâce, d'habitude, d'honneur, de part et d'autre, de suite, de toutes parts, etc.
b) De + subst. déterminé.Du moins, du reste, etc.
2/ De + adj.De droite et de gauche; de nouveau, d'ordinaire, de plus belle, etc.
3/ De + adv.De là, d'ici là, de même, d'ores et déjà, d'où, de surplus, etc.
B.− Loc. prépositives
1/ Adv. + de.Afin de, au-delà de, au-dessus de, auprès de, avant de, combien de, loin de, lors de, moins de, non loin de, peu de, près de, que de, tant de, etc.
2/ Subst. + de.
À défaut de, à titre de, au nom de, en cas de, en dépit de, en qualité de, en vertu de, faute de, histoire de, par la grâce de, par suite de, pour cause de, sous le couvert de, en signe de, sous prétexte de, en présence de, le long de, etc.
3/ Subst. déverbal + de. À l'approche de, au lever de, au sortir de, au tomber de, etc.
C.− Loc. conj. ou relatives
− De ce que, de peur que, du fait que.
− De qui, de quoi, etc.
C.− Loc. conj. ou relatives
D.− Loc. verbales. Être d'avis que, de; être d'accord, se mettre d'accord, etc.
E.− Loc. substantivales
F.− [De dans les mots composés]

Comment: Wow, that's a lot to take up. Made sure to save this for future reference.

Comment: @Nasan You might have to touch it up a bit as I worked rapidly, but there shouldn't be too much to fix up..

Comment: I  did not downvote but should not be a better idea to provide a summary of the main points of your answer? Or may be reformat it to be more readable? I guess most of the downvoting here has to do with the length of the answer. The question is a basic one that all of learners of French language have asked at least once.

Comment: @Dimitris 1/ Actually, the answer stops at the end of "I". What has been added in "II" and which is what makes that answer look long, is not anything to take as explanation but something to use as a reference, something to copy, possibly, and stach away somewhere (as the questioner did , by the way) and get back to when for instance there is a sequence of words comprising "de" and it is not clear whether the preposition is connected to the verb or to a noun ("il a donné aux élèves des devoirs", easy instance) and other  problems. (1/2)

Comment: @Dimitris  2/ The question appears to be basic but my answer is a warning to the questioner that it is not a real question: it is irrelevant to classify the relations into two groups, "possession" on the one hand and "description" on the other; the class "description" is very general and it teaches you nothing about the real relation that connects the two words. The term "possession" is used by linguists to describe one of the relations, but the term "description" is not and you have to delve deeper into the semantics of the particular combination  (2/2)

Comment: @Dimitris to extract a meaningful relation. Taking the form "le train de Paris", you  can get at least two relations depending on the context: possession (some kind of possession; Paris, ie the administration, freighted a train) and spatial origin (the train coming from paris); there is no theory for that and only one thing to tell you what is the relation, that is a combination of your knowledge of usage and your understanding of the context where you heard or read "train de Paris". (3/3)